# After installing cinderella, all "gem install" commands fails with While executing gem ... (FloatDomainError) Infinity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, homebrew, chef-infra

After installing cinderella, all "gem install" commands fails with:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (FloatDomainError)
    Infinity
```

I'm trying to use cinderella to make sure everything is the same across our development enviroments. Maybe should I go for another solution? Vagrant and chef?

[www.atmos.org/cinderella/](http://www.atmos.org/cinderella/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Later on I figure out that it was a network problem somehow. When I changed to another network (from the company's ethernet to my home wireless) it worked as expected.

Comment: Are you sure that doesn't mean it could be a firewall/proxy issue?  I am having the same issue, but I have been thinking it's proxy related.